# Casting string column to date in hql

Tags: java, string, hibernate, casting, hql

I need to get all records of date superior than 01/01/2015. This query does not work since  nt.valeur is of dataType varchar(255). I cannot change the structure of the entity NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  . 
The database server is on a db2 version 9.7.

Here is the hql:

```
select nt.valeur from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and cast(nt.valeur as date) = '01/01/2015')
```

I tried by casting cast(nt.valeur as date) but it generates an exception.

here is the exception

```
DIAVERUM 2015-01-23 13:23:21,859 [http-8081-7] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-461, SQLSTATE=42846, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.LONG VARCHAR;SYSIBM.DATE, DRIVER=3.63.75
DIAVERUM 2015-01-23 13:23:21,859 [http-8081-7] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-461;42846;SYSIBM.LONG VARCHAR|SYSIBM.DATE, DRIVER=3.63.75
```

How can I cast the  column 
What are the ways this string column can be compared as a date in an hql?

Comment: Did you try "yyyy-MM-dd" ? select nt.valeur from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and cast(nt.valeur as date) = '2015/01/01')

Comment: yes, I get same error

Comment: One last comment can u try "2015-01-01" ?

Comment: You can try `YYYY-MM-dd` format.. reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423296/hql-query-using-a-date-column#comment6149248_5429462

Comment: I tried both '2015/01/01' and '2015-01-01' but returns with same exception.

Comment: How are the `dataType` values represented in your database table? Can you post some examples?

Comment: Example of a value is 01/02/2015

Answer (score 6):

You can use db2 to_date function to cast different string formats to date.
For example

```
date(to_date(column,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

So you query could be (depends on the format used on the column `nt.valeur`)

```
select nt.valeur from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and date(to_date(nt.valeur,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')) = '01/01/2015')
```

See: [TO_DATE scalar function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007109.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-158)

to_date is actually alias for [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-153) function where format of the format string is documented better.

Comment: I get the same exception as above

Comment: String format of date might depend on locale setting. Please try `select nt.valeur from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and date(to_date(nt.valeur,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')) = date(to_date('01-01-2015 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')))`. But please edit the format string according the format of your cells.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without trying to cast string to date. Try this

```
select nt.valeur from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and concat(substring(nt.valeur, 7, 4), substring(nt.valeur, 4, 2), substring(nt.valeur, 1, 2)) > '20150101'
```

This is under assumption that `01/01/2015` from your example is `dd/MM/yyyy` (but can be changed easily), and that you can adapt the parameter format to `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: This will not compare dates ,Rather It will compare both the Strings.

Comment: @AnilUttani Yes that is the point. When in yyyyMMdd format, dates are sortable by ordinary string sort.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:-

```
from NotifTypeActionChampAddValVO  nt where nt.valide = 1  and nt.typeActionChampAdditionnelValue.champAdditionnel.id = 123  and nt.valeur ='2015-01-01'
```